# joint conditional pdf of given sum of exponential distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, \dotsc , X_n$ iid random sample of size $n$ from an exponential distribution with mean $1/λ$. and $S$ is sum of $X_i$.
Find the joint conditional pdf of $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n$ given $S$

i think $S\sim\operatorname{Gamma}(n, λ)$ and joint conditional pdf $=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc, x_n,S)/f_s(S)$

I think $f_s(S)$ is Gamma distribution's pdf but i can't calculate joint distribution pdf $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dotsc,x_n,S)$  because $S$ is sum of $X_i$. very confusing

How can solve this??

Comment: You've got $f_s(S)$ where you should have $f_S(s).$

Comment: You are right about the distribution of the sum.

Comment: Since $S$ is a function of $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, obtain $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes, but how can i calculate joint pdf about $x_1,x_2,...x_n,S$ ??

Comment: @madprob ah, really?? why??

Comment: The handwavy explanation: $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S)$ denotes how likely it is to observe $x_1,\ldots,x_n,S$. Note that, after you observe $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ it is certain to observe $S(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ (since $S$ is a function of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.  That is, it is as likely to observe $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S)$ as it is to observe $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. The rigorous explanation depends on what pre-requisites you have.

Comment: First, note that if you want the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given $X_1+\cdots+X_n,$ you're looking for a distribution on an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional space. The vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is constrained to lie within the set in which they have a particular sum and they are all nonnegative.

Comment: The bottom line will be that the conditional distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ given $S=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ is _uniform_ in the simplex $\{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) : x_1\ge0\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ x_n\ge0\ \&\ x_1+\cdots+x_n=S\}.$ And in so writing, I am being careful about the distinction between $x$ and $X,$ and that point seems somewhat neglected elsewhere in the question and in comments. But I'm not yet sure what the really simple way to explain this is.

Comment: @MichaelHardy aren't you essentially saying that $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S)= f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)I(S = S(x_1,\ldots,x_n))$?

Comment: @madprob : It seems to me you're being sloppy about several things. One is that you use the same letter, $f,$ to refer to different functions. That is unfortunately commonplace in this context, but it is pernicious when certain things are done. And I wonder at your use of a capital $S$ to refer both to a random variable and to an argument to a density function. Furthermore, you're writing of a density function of $n$ variables for a random vector constrained to lie in an $(n-1)$-dimensional space, without saying a word about what that means.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I agree that the argument is sloppy. However, I assume that the OP is taking a first course in probability. Is it possible to get rid of the sloppyness with no measure theory?
a) A function of a random variable is a random variable. Indeed, the conditional density $f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n|S}(x_1,\ldots,x_n|S)=\frac{f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n,S}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S)}{f_{S}(S)}$ is a random variable.
b) The indicator function $I(S=S(x1,…,x_n))$ shows that the n variables lie in the $(n-1)$-dimensional space. I neglected to add this indicator in my first answer. I agree that this was too sloppy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66908/discussion-between-madprob-and-michael-hardy).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is handwavy, since it doesn't explain why $(1) f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S)=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)I(S(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=S)$.
\begin{align*}
 f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n|S}(x_1,\ldots,x_n|S) 
 &= \frac{f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n,S}(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S)}{f_S(S)} \\
 &= \frac{f_{X_1,\ldots,X_n}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)I(S(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=S)}{f_S(S)} 
 & (1) \\
 &= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^{n}{f_{X_i}(x_i)I(n\bar{x}=S)}}{f_{S}(S)} 
 & n\bar{x} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i} \\
 &= \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n \lambda \exp(-\lambda x_i)I(n\bar{x}=S)}
 {\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\exp(-\lambda S)} \\
 &= \frac{\lambda^n \exp(-\lambda n\bar{x})I(n\bar{x}=S)}
 {\frac{\lambda^n}{\Gamma(n)}\exp(-\lambda S)} \\
 &= \Gamma(n) I(n\bar{x}=S)
 & \frac{\exp(-\lambda n\bar{x})I(n\bar{x}=S)}{\exp(-\lambda S)}=I(n\bar{x}=S)
\end{align*}

Comment: Note that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ follows a Dirichlet$(1,\ldots,1)$ given that $S=1$.

Comment: The original poster uses the capital $S$ as the name of a random variable. Yet you're using it both in that way and as an argument to the density function.

Comment: @MichaelHardy indeed, a conditional probability is a random variable that is defined as $P(X \leq x|S) = E[I(X \leq x)|S]$. Note that a conditional probability is a function of $S$. Similarly, the conditional density is also a random variable such that $f(x|S) = \nabla P(X \leq x|S)$. Unless there is something that I don't see, this part is rigorous.

Comment: But you wrote $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n,S). \qquad$